# Разработка классов для игры морской бой

Tags: c++, проектирование

Пишу игру морской бой.

Есть класс Game, который получает при инициализации 2 объекта типа Player. У класса Player есть Field (визуальный компонент) и класс Ships для управления кораблями. Как мне изменить местоположение поля (на визуальной форме), если это является внутренним объектом? Тут я явно запутался в проектировании классов и чувствую, что надо отходить от этого созданием абстрактного класса Field, но как тогда посылать события, которые возникают при стрельбе по полю?

Как разработать независимые классы, и чтобы это не вызвало в дальнейшем проблем?

Думаю, и дальше ещё будет более запутанно, потому что игра ещё поддерживает режим сетевой игры. А это ещё дальнейшие изменения в работе классов.

Comment: «и чтобы это не вызвало в дальнейшем проблем?» Никак. Программирование и есть решение возникающих перед программистом проблем.

Comment: @T2skler Для начала, не стоит смешивать модель и визуальное представление игры. Создайте отдельные классы для описания игровых объектов и логики (модель игры)  и их визуального представления.

Comment: @VladD: Согласен, но можно все-таки как-то спроектировать/предусмотреть это. Я просто проектированием классов совсем не занимался и трудно в это вникать. Для меня проще  бы и быстрее реализовать все это без классов кораблей, на одних флагах в поле, но вот по заданию требуется использовать классы

Comment: @rdorn: Ну, вот отделю я класс Field отдельно, напишу его абстрактную копию, но как потом взаимодействовать отдельно с ним?

Comment: @T2skler: Если вам подскажут, как правильно спроектировать, вы ничему не научитесь. Делайте не так. Напишите сами первую, неправильную архитектуру, упритесь в проблемы, выкиньте эту архитектуру полностью и напишите вторую, чуть лучше. Получите и тут проблемы и выйдите на третью. И т. д. Так вы чему-то научитесь. А если вам сразу напишут правильную архитектуру, толку будет ноль.

Comment: @Vlad: Сроки поджимают, параллельно разрабатываю приложение под андроид для университета. Да и к тому же я бы понял на одном примере, как отделить логику от интерфейса

Comment: @T2skler тогда копайте в сторону паттерна MVC и его разновидностей.

Comment: Ах, сроки, надо быстро!.. Я просто оставлю это здесь: http://norvig.com/21-days.html (перевод: http://www.williamspublishing.com/21-days.html)

Comment: @VladD: :D да это понятно, но преподавателю не скажешь: слушай, а ты подождешь до тех пор пока я полностью освою проектирование, а там я и новые фишки C++11 подтяну и все реализую ещё лучше? А может и контролы новые напишу или кроссплатформенным приложение сделаю. Только дай время на изучение Qt :)

Comment: @T2skler: Ну это да, но я бы наплевал на преподавателя (у нас обычно учат программированию средненько) и попробовал сам. Тем более вам уже дали очень хороший совет — отделить контент от представления.

Comment: Я так понял мне нужно написать некий контроллер, который будет прослойкой для общения между визуальными контролами и логикой игры. В принципе тогда и проблема решится с обработкой данной из сети - нужно будет просто изменить контроллер для сетевого режима игры

Comment: @T2skler в точку =) и вообще не важно как вы будете отображать игру, хоть на принтер каждый раунд выводите. Эх, мне бы это подсказал в свое время...

Comment: @T2skler: Короче говоря, пишите, как будто UI у вас нету, а вам нужна одна лишь логика. Когда эта часть будет готова, прикрутите UI сверху, чтобы он отображал состояние игры и отсылал команды контроллеру.